# Is there an example that a unit divisible by a prime element?

Tags: ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a UFD.

Let $u$ be a unit in $R$ and $p$ be a prime element of $R$.

Is it possible that $p|u$?

Comment: @WillJagy how do i prove this?

Comment: If $p \vert u$ then what can you say about $(p)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u$ is a unit, and $a|u$, it follows immediately that $a$ is also a unit. By definition, a unit is not prime.